# Multiple Spinners in OnItemSelected only 1 Toast working?

Tags: android, spinner, toast

Code for Spinner1 isn't working, followed the android studio tutorial for both so I don't understand why it doesn't work.

```
package com.example.keshav.szdxfcbjnm;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Adapter;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener  {

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Creation of Two spinnners
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1); //This spinner has the probem
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapr = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.pets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapr); 
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this); 
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner); 
           ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                   R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
 //maybe the probem occurs here
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);




    }
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
  switch(parent.getId()) {
      case R.id.spinner:
          String s = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
          EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
          text.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
          Toast.makeText(this, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          if (s.equals("Mars")) {
              text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

              break;
          }
      //Problem Lies Here
      case R.id.spinner1:
          String d = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));
            Toast.makeText(this, d, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
          break;

      default:
          break;

  }


}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}
   }
```

I'm a novice android developer so I apologize for the bad naming. With this code only spinner's toast is working. I was wondering if anyone could tell my why and show me how to correct it.

Comment: As the answer you lost the show()..for the future try to use the feature in Android Studio...just type Toa and the autocomplete will show you the full body of Toast..just hit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `spinner1` case, you're not calling `show()` on the toast. Change this line:

```
Toast.makeText(this, d, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

to this:

```
Toast.makeText(this, d, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```